# Linear map associated to matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, analysis, tensor-products

So matrix multiplication $m:M_2(\mathbb R)\times M_2(\mathbb R) \to M_2(\mathbb R)$ is bilinear, where we consider $M_2(\mathbb R)$, the space of  2-by-2 matrices, for simplicity.

What is the associated linear map $\tilde{m}:M_2(\mathbb R)\otimes M_2(\mathbb R) \to M_2(\mathbb R)$, which exists and is unique by the universal property of the tensor product space?

I tried to look at simple examples, e.g. the following product of matrices:

$$
m\left(\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
2 & 1
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{ll}
2 & 3 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right) \right)
$$

$$
=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
2 & 1
\end{array}\right) \cdot\left(\begin{array}{ll}
2 & 3 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$

$$
=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
2 & 3 \\
4 & 7
\end{array}\right)
$$

So we want a linear $\tilde{m}$ such that $m(A,B) = \tilde{m}(A\otimes B)$. First, the tensor product (which coincides with the Kronecker product for finite dimensional vector spaces, as far as I know) of $A$ and $B$ yields the following:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
2 & 1
\end{array}\right) \otimes\left(\begin{array}{ll}
2 & 3 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$

$$
=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
2 & 3 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right) & \left(\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right) \\
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
4 & 6 \\
0 & 2
\end{array}\right) & \left(\begin{array}{ll}
2 & 3 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
\end{array}\right)
$$

I would have no idea how to even start guessing $\tilde{m}$ so that if applied to the 4-by-4 matrix above it yields the same result as the matrix product of the two 2-by-2 matrices, i.e.  $$
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
2 & 3 \\
4 & 7
\end{array}\right)
$$.

Comment: $\bar m(E_{i,j}\otimes E_{k,l})=m(E_{i,j},E_{k,l})=\delta_{j,k}E_{i,l},$ where the $E_{i,j}$'s are the four matrices or the canonical basis of $M_2$ (one $1$ on [row $i$, column $j$], and three $0$'s elsewhere). In the $4\times4$ matrix $E_{i,j}\otimes E_{k,l},$ all elements are $0$ except one $1$.

Comment: (continued) This $1$ is on row $2(i-1)+k$ and column $2(j-1)+l.$

Comment: @Martin In a sense it's a bit tautological to say "what the associated linear map is": for any $A,B$, we have $\tilde m(A \otimes B) = AB$, and more generally
$$
\tilde m\left(\sum_i A_i \otimes B_i \right) = \sum_i A_iB_i.
$$ 
What I suspect you're really after is a **matrix representation** of the linear map. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Probably, yes. Let’s say that I am staring at the 4-by-4 matrix and are told that there exist $A,B$ whose tensor product yield the 4-by-4 matrix but don’t even know how to express this as a tensor product and would like to directly compute the result from the big matrix

Comment: (continued again) So, denoting by $E_{i,j}$ again the 16 matrices of the canonical basis of $M_4$:$$\bar m(E_{2(i-1)+k,2(j-1)+l})=\delta_{j,k}E_{i,l}.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval, your answer makes sense, but have I made a computational mistake then, since in my example you cannot "pick out" entries of the 4-by-4 matrix to obtain the desired 2-by-2 matrix? By this, I mean that the map that you defined seems to construct the 2-by-2 matrix by sending the entry $2(i-1)+k,2(j-1)+l$ in the 4-by-4 matrix to the entry $i,l$ in the 2-by-2 resulting matrix from the product. In other words, the $7$ in the small matrix cannot be recovered as an entry of the large matrix

Comment: Neither you nor I did make a mistake. Yes I we can "pick out" entries of the 4-by-4 matrix to obtain the desired 2-by-2 matrix". $\bar m$does not send all $2(i−1)+k,2(j−1)+l$ in the 4-by-4 matrix to the entry $i,l$ in the 2-by-2 resulting matrix: only those for which j=k. E.g. $7E_{2,2}=\bar m(2\cdot3 E_{2(2-1)+1,2(1-1)+2}+E_{2(2-1)+2,2(2-1)+2})$

Comment: (I checked, it is correct:) $7E_{2,2}=\bar m(6E_{3,2}+E_{4,4}).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a matrix representation of the linear map, we need a basis/coordinate representation for $M_2(\Bbb R)$ and ${M_2(\Bbb R)} \otimes {M_2(\Bbb R)}$.
One convenient representation for the codomain is to represent $A \in M_2(\Bbb R)$ with the vector $\operatorname{vec}(A) \in \Bbb R^{2^2}$. For vectors $u,v \in \Bbb R^2$, we have
$$
\operatorname{vec}(uv^T) = v \bar \otimes u,
$$
where $\bar \otimes$ is the usual Kronecker product.

Similarly, a convenient representation for the domain comes from taking the coordinate vector of $A \otimes B$ to be the [column-major vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) $\operatorname{vec}(A \bar \otimes B) \in \Bbb R^{2^4}$, where $\bar \otimes$ denotes the usual Kronecker product. Note that for column vectors $u,v,x,y \in \Bbb R^2$,
$$
\operatorname{vec}((uv^T) \bar \otimes (xy^T)) = \operatorname{vec}((u\bar \otimes x)(v \bar \otimes y)^T) = (v \bar \otimes y) \bar \otimes (u\bar\otimes x).
$$
Putting all that together, the matrix of this linear map is the unique matrix $M$ for which we have $M\operatorname{vec}(A\bar \otimes B) = \operatorname{vec}(AB)$. For inputs of the form $A = uv^T, B = xy^T$, we have $AB = uv^Txy^T = (v^Tx) \cdot uy^T$. This means that $M$ needs to satisfy
$$
M[v \bar \otimes y \bar \otimes u \bar \otimes x] = (v^Tx) \cdot y \bar\otimes u.
$$
One way to build such a matrix is to use the standard basis of $\Bbb R^2$. If $e_1,e_2$ denote the standard basis vectors $(1,0),(0,1)$, then our matrix will be
$$
M = \sum_{1 \leq i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4 \leq 2} e_{i_1} \bar \otimes e_{i_2} \bar \otimes e_{i_3} \bar \otimes e_{i_4} = (e_{i_1}^T e_{i_4}) e_{i_2} \bar \otimes e_{i_3}.
$$
This gives us the matrix
$$
M = \left[\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right].
$$

---

An illustrative example: if $A,B$ are the matrices
$$
A = \left[\begin{matrix}0 & 1\\2 & 3\end{matrix}\right], 
\quad B = \left[\begin{matrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{matrix}\right],
$$
Then the vector representation of $A\otimes B$ is
$$
x = \operatorname{vec}(A\bar \otimes B) = 
\left[\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 0\end{array}\right]^T,
$$
and the vector representation of $AB$ is
$$
y = \operatorname{vec}(AB) = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 3 & 0 & 2\end{matrix}\right]^T.
$$
I will leave it to you to verify that we indeed have $Mx = y$.

---

Question: can we write this function in the form $\tilde m(A \bar \otimes B) = P(A \bar \otimes B)Q$ (where $P$ has shape $2 \times 4$ and $Q$ shape $4 \times 2$)?

Suppose that $m$ could be written in such a form. Note that
$$
\operatorname{vec}[P(A\bar \otimes B)Q] = (Q^T \otimes P)\operatorname{vec}(A \bar \otimes B).
$$
In other words, it would follow that the matrix $M$ of our linear map could be expressed in the form $Q^T \otimes P$ for some $P,Q$ of shapes $2\times 4, 4 \times 2$.

Now, here's a trick to check whether this is possible. There is a permutation of the entries of $Q^T \otimes P$ that results in the matrix $\operatorname{vec}(P)\operatorname{vec}(Q^T)^T$. If that permutation is applied to $M$, then we can deduce that $m$ is expressible in the hypothesized form if and only if the resulting matrix has rank 1.

For the specific form of that permutation: note as before that for $u,y \in \Bbb R^2$ and $v,x \in \Bbb R^4$,
$$
\operatorname{vec}((uv^T) \otimes (xy^T)) = v \otimes  y \otimes u\otimes x.
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\operatorname{vec}(\operatorname{vec}(uv^T)\operatorname{vec}(xy^T)^T) = 
\operatorname{vec}((v \otimes u)  (y \otimes x)^T) = 
y \otimes x \otimes v \otimes u.
$$
So, we can vectorize $M$, apply a permutation that takes $v \otimes  y \otimes u\otimes x \mapsto y \otimes x \otimes v \otimes u$, then unvectorize the result into a $4 \times 4$ matrix.

Going through through this process results in the matrix
$$
\hat M = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right],
$$
which has rank 2 instead of 1. Thus, $m$ cannot be expressed in the form $\tilde m(A \otimes B) = P(A \otimes B)Q$. However, it **can** be expressed in the form
$$
P_1(A \otimes B)Q_1 + P_2(A \otimes B)Q_2
$$
for suitable matrices $P_1,P_2,Q_1,Q_2$. More specifically, taking
$$
P_1 = 
\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right],
\quad Q_1 = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\\0 & 0\\0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]\\
\quad P_2 = 
\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right], 
\quad Q_2 = 
\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 0\\0 & 0\\1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]
$$
We have
$$
P_1 (A \otimes B)Q_1 + P_2 (A \otimes B)Q_2 = AB.
$$

---

The above decomposition generalizes nicely into the following generalized formula. For $A,B$ of size $n \times n$, let $e_1,\dots,e_n \in \Bbb R^n$ denote the standard basis and $I$ the identity matrix of size $n$. We have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (I \otimes e_i)^T(A \otimes B)(e_i \otimes I) = AB,\\
\sum_{i=1}^n (e_i \otimes I)^T(A \otimes B)(I \otimes e_i) = BA.
$$
Index-wise, the first of these amounts to
$$
(AB)_{j,k} = \sum_{i=1}^n (e_j \otimes e_i)^T(A \otimes B)(e_i \otimes e_k)
= \sum_{i=1}^n (A \otimes B)_{[n(j-1)+i, n(i-1)+k]}.
$$

As a proof, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_i(I \otimes e_i)^T(A \otimes B)(e_i \otimes I) &= 
\sum_i (IAe_i) \otimes (e_i^TBI) 
\\ &=
\sum_i \underbrace{(IAe_i)}_{\text{column vector}} \otimes 
\underbrace{(e_i^TB)}_{\text{row vector}}
\\&= \sum_i Ae_ie_i^TB = 
A\left(\sum_i e_ie_i^T\right)B = AIB = AB.
\end{align}
$$

For the second formula:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_i(e_i \otimes I)^T(A \otimes B)(I \otimes e_i) &= 
\sum_i (e_i^TAI) \otimes (IBe_i) 
\\ &=
\sum_i \underbrace{(e_i^TA)}_{\text{row vector}} \otimes 
\underbrace{(B e_i)}_{\text{column vector}}
\\&= \sum_i Be_ie_i^TA = 
B\left(\sum_i e_ie_i^T\right)A = BIA = BA.
\end{align}
$$

---

Relevant code (Python), for anyone interested in reproducing my computations.

```
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
import sympy as sp

n = 2 # matrix size

# define iterated tensor product
def kron(*args):
    return reduce(np.kron,args)

# Produce the matrix M
M = np.zeros([n**2, n**4],dtype = int)
for j,(i1,i2,i3,i4) in enumerate(product(range(n),repeat = 4)):
    M[n*i2+i3,j] = int(i1==i4)

# Produce permutation matrix
P = np.zeros([n**6,n**6],dtype = int)
for v,y,u,x in product(np.eye(n**2,dtype=int),np.eye(n,dtype=int),
                       np.eye(n,dtype=int),np.eye(n**2,dtype=int)):
    P += kron(v,y,u,x)[:,None]*kron(y,x,v,u)[None,:]

# apply transformation to get the (rank-n) matrix $\hat M$
m_hat = (P@M.ravel(order = 'F')).reshape([n**3,n**3],order='F')

print(np.linalg.matrix_rank(m_hat))
```

Faster version:

```
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
import sympy as sp

n = 2 # matrix size

# define iterated tensor product
def kron(*args):
    return reduce(np.kron,args)

# Produce the matrix M
M = np.zeros([n**2, n**4],dtype = int)

idx = [(n*i2 + i3,j) for j,(i1,i2,i3,i4) in enumerate(product(range(n),repeat = 4)) if i1==i4]
row,col = zip(*idx)
M[row,col] = 1

# Produce the permutation applied in m->m_hat transformation
perm = [c + a*n + d*n**3 + b*n**4
       for a,b,c,d in product(range(n**2),range(n**2),range(n),range(n))]
m_hat = M.ravel(order='F')[perm].reshape(n**3,n**3,order = 'F')

# check the rank
np.linalg.matrix_rank(m_hat)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ben. This may be a groping-in-the-dark kind of question, but can't we get two matrices, one 2-by-4 called $X$ and another 4-by-2 called $\tilde{X}$, such that $A$ and $B$ act directly on the unvectorised $A\otimes B$? I.e., something like 
$$m(A,B) = \tilde{m}(A\otimes B) = X \cdot (A\otimes B) \cdot \tilde{X} \in M_2.$$

I'm reasoning by some kind of analogy to quadratic forms, although the analogy may be ill-founded.

Comment: @MartinGeller Most likely, the answer is no. In order to express general maps from $M_2 \otimes M_2$ to $M_2$, one typically needs a sum of the form
$$
\tilde m(A \otimes B) = \sum_i X_i(A \otimes B) \tilde X_i.
$$

Comment: @MartinGeller See my latest edit. The answer is definitively no.

Comment: Ben, I think I grasped the intuition of what you have done. Correct me if I’m wrong. Let $v,w\in V$ for some finite dimensional vector space $V$. Every bilinear form $B$ on $V$ has for a fixed basis an associated matrix $(A)_{i,j}=B(e_i,e_j)$, where $\beta=\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a basis of $V$. Then we have that $B(v,w)= [v]_\beta^T A [w]_\beta$, and where  $[v]_\beta = (v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is a $nx1$ column vector containing the coefficients of $v$ in $\beta$. Now, in our case, obtaining these column vectors $[v]_\beta$ and $[w]_\beta$ with $v,w\in M_2(\mathbb R)$, amounts to…

Comment: …vectorising the matrices $v$ and $w$. Then, I wouldn’t know how to take from here, but I did understand the above which said in other words is: bilinear forms $B$ on $n$-dimensional vector spaces $V$ with basis $\beta$ are in one-to-one correspondence (if I’m not mistaken) with $n$-by-$n$ matrices such that $\forall v,w\in V,$ $B(v,w)= [v]_\beta^T A [w]_\beta$. To associate a bilinear form on 2-by-2 matrices (a 4-dimensional vector space) to an $n$-by-$n$  matrix (which will be 4-by-4), we need to express $v,w$ in the basis $\beta$ (aka “vectorising” the matrices $v$ and $w$)…

Comment: and then write $[v]_\beta^T A [w]_\beta = [v]_\beta^T (B(e_i,e_j))_{i,j} [w]_\beta  $ which will then be equal to $B(v,w)$

Comment: @Martin Honestly, I have no idea what you're trying to say here. What exactly is the relevant "bilinear form"?

Comment: Apologies, matrix multiplication $m$ is the bilinear form. Replacing $B$ by $m$ may improve the explanation a little bit

Comment: @Martin That doesn't make sense because matrix multiplication produces a vector (i.e. the matrix $AB$) rather than the scalar, which is what your $B$ produces and what bilinear *forms* definitionally produce. I suppose you could regard the the entries of $AB$ as being separate bilinear functions of $A$ and $B$ though

Comment: Argh, good point! At least you got me thinking a bit. Yes I guess that $AB$ would define $n^2$ $n$-by-$n$ matrices for each bilinear *form* associated to each entry. This would amount to an $n^3$-by-$n^3$ matrix “worth of data”, an awful lot bigger than what you’ve produced